# Zendframework 3 - Can't get entityManager on Application/Module

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, doctrine, zend-framework3

I use Zendframework 3 and I have followed the tutorial for User authentication. In this project I'm able to connect to my database using entityManager. Then I created another project and copied the required code to make ORM work but I'm not able to retrieve information.

I have read my code 1000 time, no error in log, every factory is correctly mapped.

Here's my configuration:

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "mvc",
        "zf"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.3 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.0.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-form": "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugins": "^1.0.1",
        "zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7.1",
        "zendframework/zend-authentication": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "1.1.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "^1.4",
        "zendframework/zend-math": "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-crypt": "^3.1",
        "zendframework/zend-captcha": "^2.6",
        "zendframework/zend-mail": "^2.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/"
        }
    },
    "extra": [],
    "scripts": {
        "development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
        "development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
        "development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
        "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php"
    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            // .. OTHER ROUTES
            'tienda' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/tienda[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\TiendaController::class,
                        'action'        => 'tienda',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => Controller\Factory\IndexControllerFactory::class,
            Controller\TiendaController::class => Controller\Factory\TiendaControllerFactory::class,
            Controller\BlogController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            Service\MailSender::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            Service\ImageManager::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    // The following registers our custom view 
    // helper classes in view plugin manager.
    'view_helpers' => [
        'factories' => [
            View\Helper\Menu::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            View\Helper\Breadcrumbs::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
        'aliases' => [
            'mainMenu' => View\Helper\Menu::class,
            'pageBreadcrumbs' => View\Helper\Breadcrumbs::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        /*
         * You typically set the display_not_found_reason and display_exceptions
         * parameters to false in production systems, because you don't want site
         * visitors see the details about errors in your site. However, you will
         * still be able to retrieve the detailed information from Apache's
         * error.log file.
         */
        'display_not_found_reason' => false,
        'display_exceptions'       => false,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
    'doctrine' => [
        'driver' => [
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity']
            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Factory

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Application\Service\MailSender;
use Application\Controller\TiendaController;

/**
 * This is the factory for UserController. Its purpose is to instantiate the
 * controller and inject dependencies into it.
 */
class TiendaControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $mailSender = $container->get(MailSender::class);
        $sessionContainer = $container->get(SessionManager::class);
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        // Instantiate the controller and inject dependencies
        return new TiendaController($mailSender, $entityManager, $sessionContainer);
    }
}
```

TiendaController.php

```
<?php
    namespace Application\Controller;

    use Zend\Mail;
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
    use Application\Entity\User;
    // use Zend\Session\Container; // We need this when using sessions
    use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

    use Application\Entity\Categoria;
    use Application\Entity\Producto;
    use Application\Entity\Marca;

    class TiendaController extends AbstractActionController
    {

        /**
         * Session manager.
         * @var Zend\Session\SessionManager
         */
        private $sessionManager;

        /**
         * Mail sender.
         * @var Application\Service\MailSender
         */
        private $mailSender;

        /**
         * Entity manager.
         * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
         */
        private $entityManager;

        /**
         * Constructor. 
         */
        public function __construct($mailSender, $entityManager, $sessionManager)
        {
            $this->mailSender = $mailSender;
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
            $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
        }

        public function tiendaAction()
        {
            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function categoryAction()
        {
            // Checks if this is a Javascript request
            $xmlHttpRequst = $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest();

            if ($xmlHttpRequst) {
                $titles = [];
                for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
                    $titles[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor {$i}";
                }

                $view = new JsonModel($titles);
                /**
                 * Tell the renderer not to show the layout
                 * by setting setTerminal to true
                 */
                $view->setTerminal(true); 
            } else {
                // IS NOT THROWING AN ERROR AND IT RETURNS AN EMPTY ARRAY
                $categories = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Categoria::class)->findAll();
                $brands = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Marca::class)->findAll();

                return new ViewModel(array(
                    'categories' => $categories,
                    'brands' => $brands
                ));
            }     

            return $view; 
        }

        public function getProductosAction()
        {
            // Checks if this is a Javascript request
            $xmlHttpRequst = $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest();

            if (! $xmlHttpRequst) {
                die('Bad request');
            }

            $categoryId = $this->request->getPost('categoryId');
            $brandId = $this->request->getPost('brandId');
            $priceId = $this->request->getPost('priceId');

            $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

            $mayor_a = 0;
            $menor_a = 1000000000;

            switch($priceId) {
                case 1: {
                    $mayor_a = 0;
                    $menor_a = 999.99;
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    $mayor_a = 1000;
                    $menor_a = 4999.99;
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    $mayor_a = 5000;
                    $menor_a = 9999.99;
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    $mayor_a = 10000;
                    $menor_a = 49999.99;
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    $mayor_a = 50000;
                    $menor_a = 1000000000;
                    break;
                }
            }

            $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery('SELECT * FROM pm_producto');
            $products = $query->execute();

            $view = new JsonModel();
            // Set data to be used in the view
            // $view->setVariable('productos', $productos);
            $view->setVariable('is_xmlhttprequest', true);
            $view->setVariable('categoryId', $categoryId);
            $view->setVariable('brandId', $brandId);
            $view->setVariable('mayor_a', $mayor_a);
            $view->setVariable('menor_a', $menor_a);
            $view->setVariable('products', $products);

            /**
             * Tell the renderer not to show the layout
             * by setting setTerminal to true
             */
            $view->setTerminal(true);

            return $view;
        }

        public function getProductoAction()
        {
            // Checks if this is a Javascript request
            $xmlHttpRequst = $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest();

            if (! $xmlHttpRequst) {
                die('Bad request');
            }

            $productId = $this->request->getPost('productId');
            //$product = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)->findOneById($productId);

            $view = new JsonModel();
            // Set data to be used in the view
            $product = json_encode(
              '[{"id":"1","avatarUrl":"https://hiset.ets.org/rsc/img/icons/icon-tt-checklist.svg","nombre":"Hola soy prueba","descripcion":"Hola soy una descripcion de equipo medico"}]'
            );
            $view->setVariable('product', $product);

            /**
             * Tell the renderer not to show the layout
             * by setting setTerminal to true
             */
            $view->setTerminal(true);

            return $view;
        }

        public function searchAction()
        {
            // Checks if this is a Javascript request
            $xmlHttpRequst = $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest();

            if (! $xmlHttpRequst) {
                die('Bad request');
            }

            $categoryId = $this->request->getPost('categoryId');
            $brandId = $this->request->getPost('brandId');
            $priceId = $this->request->getPost('priceId');

            $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery(
                  'SELECT * FROM pm_producto u WHERE u.'
            );
            $products = $query->execute();

            $view = new JsonModel();
            // Set data to be used in the view
            $view->setVariable('products', $products);

            /**
             * Tell the renderer not to show the layout
             * by setting setTerminal to true
             */
            $view->setTerminal(true);

            return $view;
        }

        public function cartAction()
        {
            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function checkoutAction()
        {

            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function payAction()
        {

            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function confirmAction()
        {

            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function successfulAction()
        {
            $mail = new Mail\Message();
            $mail->setBody($email->getValue('message'));
            $mail->setFrom($email->getValue('email'), $email->getValue('personal'));
            $mail->addTo($this->reciverAddress, $this->reciverName);
            $mail->setSubject($email->getValue('subject'));

            $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();

            $transport->send($mail);
            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function unsuccessfulAction()
        {
            return new ViewModel();
        }

    }
```

local.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Local Configuration Override
 *
 * This configuration override file is for overriding environment-specific and
 * security-sensitive configuration information. Copy this file without the
 * .dist extension at the end and populate values as needed.
 *
 * @NOTE: This file is ignored from Git by default with the .gitignore included
 * in ZendSkeletonApplication. This is a good practice, as it prevents sensitive
 * credentials from accidentally being committed into version control.
 */

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver as PDOMySqlDriver;

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',                    
                    'user'     => 'test',
                    'password' => 'test',
                    'dbname'   => 'test',
                ]
            ],            
        ],        
    ],
];
```

modules.config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Zend\Paginator',
    'Zend\Mail',
    'Zend\I18n',
    'Zend\InputFilter',
    'Zend\Filter',
    'Zend\Hydrator',
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Cache',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application'
];
```

UPDATE #1

Entity/Categoria
`

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * This class represents a registered user.
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="pm_categoria")
 */
class Categoria 
{

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="ca_id")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="ca_created")  
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="ca_modified")  
 */
protected $modifiedAt;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(name="ca_name")  
 */
protected $name;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(name="ca_description")  
 */
protected $description;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(name="ca_avatar_thumb_file_id")  
 */
protected $avatarUrl;


public function getId() 
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) 
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getCreatedAt() 
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

public function setCreatedAt($createdAt) 
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
}

public function getModifiedAt() 
{
    return $this->modifiedAt;
}

public function setModifiedAt($modifiedAt) 
{
    $this->modifiedAt = $modifiedAt;
}

public function getName() 
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) 
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getDescription() 
{
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription($description) 
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

public function getAvatarUrl() 
{
    return $this->avatarUrl;
}

public function setAvatarUrl($avatarUrl) 
{
    $this->avatarUrl = $avatarUrl;
}
```

}`

After executing `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql`

```
ALTER TABLE pm_producto DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_ID_CATEGORY;
ALTER TABLE pm_producto DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_ID_MARCA;
DROP INDEX FK_ID_CATEGORY ON pm_producto;
DROP INDEX FK_ID_MARCA ON pm_producto;
ALTER TABLE pm_producto CHANGE pd_id pd_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_id_categoria pd_id_categoria VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_id_marca pd_id_marca VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_created pd_created VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_modified pd_modified VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_available pd_available VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_name pd_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_description pd_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_price pd_price VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE pd_avatar_thumb_file_id pd_avatar_thumb_file_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE pm_categoria CHANGE ca_id ca_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE ca_created ca_created VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE ca_modified ca_modified VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE ca_name ca_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE ca_description ca_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE ca_avatar_thumb_file_id ca_avatar_thumb_file_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE pm_detalle_factura DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_ID_PRODUCTO;
DROP INDEX FK_ID_PRODUCTO ON pm_detalle_factura;
ALTER TABLE pm_detalle_factura CHANGE df_id df_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE df_id_producto df_id_producto VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE df_created df_created VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE df_id_factura df_id_factura VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE df_cantidad df_cantidad VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE pm_marca CHANGE mr_id mr_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE mr_created mr_created VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE mr_name mr_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE pm_factura CHANGE fa_id fa_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE fa_created fa_created VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE fa_name fa_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE fa_nit fa_nit VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE fa_total fa_total VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE fa_paid fa_paid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

UPDATE #2

I make it worked using `createQueryBuilder` like this:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('s')
                ->from('Application\Entity\Marca', 's');
$obj = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? It sounds like maybe you're getting an empty result from the ORM in `TiendaController` that you don't expect?

Comment: Hello avy, that’s correct, so let’s assume in my database table I have four records, in my controller I get an array of four object but each is an empty object. It’s like ORM is not mapping the values in my Entity

Comment: You should post the entity with the annotations as well.  Have you updated the mapping with the doctrine cli tool? Something like `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` will show if it's up to date and might inform you of errors

Comment: Already update my question with one of my Entities and the result after executing the command you say.

Comment: Yeah definitely run that SQL - `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force` will do it (only run that command on a test db where you don't mind losing data).  There might be other problems with the mapping but at least it'll mean your db is in sync with your entities before you debug further.

Comment: Awesome avy, I'll try, just one question, do you you what happens to the foreign keys I'm using? I check the commands and apparently the foreign keys are being drop, am I right?

Comment: Btw, it didn't worked, I'm still getting empty results. I mean, if I add a record on my table, then on my `TiendaController` after `$brands = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Marca::class)->findAll();` returns an array with one object but the object is empty

Comment: Yes, the foreign keys will be dropped.  Without digging through your code, it's not unlikely the reason you're not getting the results you would like is that doctrine doesn't know about the relationships between entities.   You can rebuild the relationships in doctrine using association mappings: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Still not able to make it work. Entities are not being map, I just get empty objects. I even removed my foreign keys.